# eclipse compile does not start problem

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, java

Hi i was developing java project on eclipse. Everything was ok. In a moment some windows java permission screen occured and i click to don t give a permission. After that time i could not compile my any project again. When i tried to run (after pressing f11) i got this message on the console:

< terminated > main [Java Application] C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe

i think it is not a compiletion error because compile process does not start. I tried to reinstal jres but it didn t solve my problem. Do you know what is the problem about this and how can i fix it?

Comment: You should accept some of the answers to questions you have already posted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to go to `Control Panel > Windows Firewall` and select `Restore defaults` but if you don't want to lose other settings, you could try `Advanced Settings` and find eclipse in there.